# Proving $\int_{1}^{+\infty} (\frac1x - \ln{(1+\frac1x)}) dx$ converges or not

Tags: integration

How can we prove that the following integral:

$$\int_{1}^{+\infty} (\frac1x - \ln{(1+\frac1x)}) dx$$

converges or not?

I guess it should somehow get use of some form of comparison test, but I’m not sure.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot just evaluate the improper integral?  It follows that it converges (to $-1+2\ln 2$, unless I made some mistake) by using $$\int_1^N \frac{1}{x}\,dx = \ln(N) \\ \int_1^N \ln(x)\,dx = N\ln(N) - N + 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: By L'Hopital's Rule (or series exapnsion) $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac {y-ln (1+y)} {y^{2}} \to \frac  1 2$. Put $x=\frac 1 y$ and compare the given integral with the integral of $\frac 1 {x^{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

Using the series expansion of $\ln \left( 1 + x \right)$, we get $\ln \left( 1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{x} - \frac{1}{2x^2} + \frac{1}{3x^3} - \ldots$, which converges for $x > 1$. Using this, we get that 
\begin{align*}
\int_1^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{x} - \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{x} \right) \right)dx =& \int_0^{\infty} \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} \frac{1}{kx^k}dx \\
=& \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^k}dx \\
=& \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k(k-1)} \\
=& \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k-1} - \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k} \\
=& -\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{k} - \sum_{k=2}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{k} \\
=& 2\ln(2) - 1
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Note that $y-1 \ge \ln(y)\ge \frac{y-1}{y}$ for all $y>0$. Use that (with $y=1+\frac{1}{x}$) to prove that the expression in your integral can be bounded by 0 and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ (up to a constant), which is integrable in that interval.